# Unity private counter variable initialized to wrong value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code that is supposed to control a simple AI to pace left and right 2 seconds at a time. I use nextSwitch to indicate when the movement should be multiplied by -1. For some reason, nextSwitch is initialized to like 28.938 or any other value when I play the game, so the AI just moves in one direction for 29 seconds until it starts pacing like it should. As as I keep rerunning my game, the nextSwitch value is almost always initialized to some number (like 29.938) and then after some runs it just goes up to like 35.394 and stays there for a bit and so on...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "AIController", menuName = "InputController/AIController")]



public class AIController : InputController
{
    private float movement = -1f;
    private float switchRate = 2f;
    private float nextSwitch = 0f;
    



    public override bool RetrieveJumpInput() {
        
        return true;
    }

    public override float RetrieveMoveInput() {

        Debug.Log("test " + Time.timeSinceLevelLoad + "    " + nextSwitch);
        
        if (Time.time > nextSwitch) { 
            nextSwitch = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad + switchRate;
            movement =  movement * (-1f);
        }

        return movement;
    }
}
```

I already saw a couple of suggestions so this is what I've tried:

- set nextSwitch to private
- tried using it as SerializeField but idk what that should even do so I reverted the changes
- initialized it to the value of a different variable that is private static readonly float, but that didn't change it either.

I'm not changing the variable anywhere else in a script. I used this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcw6nuc2uaU&list=WL&index=1) to make movable players in unity and now I'm just editing the AIController to be more useful.

Comment: Mixing `Time.time` and `Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` may be confusing since they aren't telling you the same thing. I'd choose one or the other.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I was using only Time.time initially. I was trying to use Time.timeSinceLevelLoad while troubleshooting. It's not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Are you calling this function from `Awake` anywhere? The documentation for Time.time says "This value is undefined during Awake messages and starts after all of these messages are finished." and that presumably applies to timeSinceLevelLoad as well since it is the same value minus an offset..

Comment: I don't know what you meant by ```Awake``` however how would that make nextSwitch have the wrong value?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use a timer to accomplish this like this:

```
bool rightorleft = false;

    System.Timers.Timer T = new System.Timers.Timer();
    T.Interval = 2000;
    T.Elapsed += delegate
{
        if(rightorleft == false) rightorleft = true;
        else{ rightorleft = false;}

};
```